# Embedded C/C++ Atollic

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++

When working on embedded c++/c projects in atollic (eclipse is just the same), under your project settings, you have:

```
> Assembler (arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -c)
> C Compiler (arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -c)
> C++ Compiler (arm-atollic-eabi-g++ -c)
> C++ Linker
```

This means, I can use C code without any modification within a c++ project, since all .c files are compiled with `gcc` and all `.cpp` files with g++. Also, if and when C code would have the `#if __cplusplus extern "C" {` within the header OR the `.cpp` code would include V code like `"#if __cplusplus extern "C" { #include "c_header.h" ...` this would make absolutely no difference since the .c file is being compiled with `gcc` which doesnt define `__cplusplus`.

> Is this correct??

When I would like to purely build with g++ since all my C code is being included this way...

```
extern "C" {
    #include "c_header.h"
}
```

How can I delete the C compiler from atollic/eclipse?

I tried removing the tools defined within the project file ".cproject", then opening the project again, but they were added automatically.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question was 2 years ago, so I doubt the original author needs assistance here, but for others.

As far as I can tell he wants to remove the C compiler from the compilation process.

You can change the file associations for C++ compiler to include .c and .h. Then remove the associations for those for the C compiler. I think that should work.

Comment: hello, 2 years is a long time, but i still havent figured out how to do this. the original question was how to build c and c++ source with g++ since g++ will see extern "C" and build (mangle) it as c source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ ->Language Mappings -> Add

Then add two associations:

```
Content type : C Header file
Language : GNU C++
```

and

```
Content type : C Source file
Language : GNU C++
```